# How to get value of numbers with space

Tags: python, regex

I used to have strings like this:

```
233.43 USD
634,233 EURO
```

and I used to extract numbers from those strings using this:

```
def extractNumbersFromString(value): #This function is to get the numbers froma string
        return re.search('(\d+(?:[.,]\d*)*)', value).group(1)
```

Now I got strings like these as well:

```
2300 000 USD
430 000 EU
```

where there is a space between the numbers and the **zeros on the right**.

How can I adjust my code to extract the numbers from those strings?

Required output:

```
 2300000 
 430000
```

My code currently gives me just this `2300` and `430` (i.e. **without the zeros on the right**).

Comment: So you need `2300 000` as the output for `2300 000 USD` and not `2300` as you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below regex.

```
>>> s = '''2300 000 USD
430 000 EU'''
>>> re.findall(r'\d+(?:[ ,.]\d+)*', s)
['2300 000', '430 000']
>>> [i.replace(' ','') for i in re.findall(r'\d+(?:[\s,.]\d+)*', s)]
['2300000', '430000']
```

Use `replace` function at the final to remove spaces in the numbers.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nE7eK4/1)

Comment: your code returns `230 000` instead of `230000` may you edit it please?

Comment: Thanks, do you mean to make this ` **return** [i.replace(' ','') for i in re.findall(r'\d+(?:[\s,.]\d+)*', s)]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need `rsplit` and to `str.replace` the spaces:

```
s="""233.43 USD
634,233 EURO
2300 000 USD
430 000 EU
"""


for line in s.splitlines():
    a,_=  line.rsplit(None, 1)
    print(a.replace(" ",""))


233.43
634,233
2300000
430000
```

Or using translate may be slightly faster:

```
for line in s.splitlines():
    a,_= line.rsplit(None, 1)
    print(a.translate(None," "))
```

If value is always a line from your input example:

```
def extractNumbersFromString(value):
    a, _= value.rsplit(None, 1)
    return a.translate(None," ")
```

Or use it with re:

```
def extractNumbersFromString(value): #This function is to get the numbers froma string
    return [a.translate(None," ") for a in re.findall('(\d+(?:[ .,]\d*)*)', value)]
```

You can also rstrip the letters:

```
from string import ascii_letters
for line in s.splitlines():
   print line.rstrip(ascii_letters).translate(None," ")
```

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli then you want to concat the strings which I did not see in your question.

Comment: i really appreciate the efforts, but as you saw, my function returns the value, but in your case, you make a loop and no return value

Comment: What is your actual input?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) with multiple deletions and no replacement characters:

```
txt='''\
233.43 USD
634,233 EURO
2300 000 USD
430 000 EU'''

import re

def extractNumbersFromString(value):    
    return re.search(r'^(\d+)', value.translate(None, " ,.")).group(1)      

for line in txt.splitlines():
    print "{:>20}    =>{:>10}".format(line, extractNumbersFromString(line))
```

Prints:

```
      233.43 USD    =>     23343
    634,233 EURO    =>    634233
    2300 000 USD    =>   2300000
      430 000 EU    =>    430000
```

If you know you are only interested in one grouping of digits per line, you can just [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) out the non digit characters as well:

```
def extractNumbersFromString(value):      
    return filter(str.isdigit, value)
```